# Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘location’, should be from class “character” or a subclass (was class “logical”)

Tags: r, twitter, types

I was trying to use getUser() function in twitteR package as:

```
library(twitteR)

api_key <- "xxx"
api_secret <- "xxx"
access_token <- "xxx"
access_token_secret <- "xxx"

setup_twitter_oauth(api_key,api_secret,access_token,access_token_secret)

userUSC <- getUser("usc_analytics")
```

The authentication part got through. Yet, I got an error executing the last line:

`Error: invalid assignment for reference class field ‘location’, should be from class “character” or a subclass (was class “logical”)`

I didn't fully understand the error message but it seems like R accidentally recognized my characters "usc_analytics" as logical variable. My friend tried on her laptop with the exact same lines and it went through without an error.

Dose anyone have any clue on what is happening here?

Did I mess up some kinds of default settings?

Thank you guys!

PS. Here's my sessionInfo()

```
R version 3.3.1 (2016-06-21)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] twitteR_1.1.9

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] bit_1.1-12    httr_1.2.1    rjson_0.2.15  R6_2.1.2      DBI_0.4-1    
[6] tools_3.3.1   curl_1.1      bit64_0.9-5   openssl_0.9.4
```

And here's the traceback():

```
16: stop(gettextf("invalid assignment for reference class field %s, should be from class %s or a subclass (was class %s)", 
    sQuote(fieldName), dQuote(fieldClass), dQuote(class(value))), 
    call. = FALSE)
15: methods:::.setDummyField(.self, ".->location", "character", "location", 
    FALSE, value)
14: (function (value) 
{
    if (missing(value)) 
        `.->location`
    else {
        methods:::.setDummyField(.self, ".->location", "character", 
            "location", FALSE, value)
        value
    }
})(quote(NA))
13: .Object$initialize(...)
12: initialize(value, ...)
11: initialize(value, ...)
10: methods::new(def, ...)
9: statusFactory$new(json)
8: buildStatus(json[["status"]])
7: .Object$initialize(...)
6: initialize(value, ...)
5: initialize(value, ...)
4: methods::new(def, ...)
3: userFactory$new(json)
2: buildUser(twInterfaceObj$doAPICall(paste("users", "show", sep = "/"), 
   params = params, ...))
1: getUser("usc_analytics")
```

Comment: Did you start with a fresh R session? Did your friend have the same package versions in their `sessionInfo()`? Perhaps you can post the `traceback()` right after you get the error as well.

Comment: No problem I'll edit the post with traceback() now. And yes, I have tried restart R session, restart Rstudio, and even reinstall all related packaged and Rstudio itself trying to erase any invisible setting. But nothing worked.